# Cron tab expression for running a job every second Sunday using Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

How do I create a cron expression for a job that I need to run every second Sunday at 7 AM in the morning?

For example

```
25th Nov 7:00:00
9th Dec  7:00:00
23rd Dec 7:00:00
```

I am using Rundeck for this automation.

Answer (score -1):

Here second Sunday (7 am) on each month

0 0 7 ? 1/1 SUN#2 *

Comment: will this run on every second sunday of the month. I mean my requirement is to schedule it every second Sunday, irrespective of how much ever sundays there are in a month.